# Regular expressions representing BNF

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, jflex

I am working on a lexer. I need to identify patterns in BNF and specify them using Regular expressions. I know there are TOKENS  e.g. keywords, identifiers, operators etc. So far I have defined Regular expressions:

```
 digit=[0-9]
    integer={digit}+
    letter=[a-zA-Z]
```

But the given BNF rule for Identifier is:

```
   < id > ::= < letter >
                | "_"
                | < id > < digit >
                | < id > < letter >
```

Since the <id> is defined by Recursive pattern, how can I express this pattern using Regular expression.
I tried this Regular expression: `id={letter}+|"_"|{id}{digit}+` for the above BNF rule but it is giving me error that Regular expression contains cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the BNF we can see that an `<id>` can begin with a letter or underscore. We can also see that an `<id>` can be followed by either a digit or letter and it is still a valid `<id>`. This is implies that an `<id>` begins with either a letter or underscore and can be followed by 0 or more digits or letters. This suggests the following regular expression:

```
id = [a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

1. `[a-zA-Z_]` Matches a letter or '_'
2. `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` Matches a digit or letter 0 or more times.

But since you already have {digit} and {letter} already defined as individual character classes, this would be using JFlex (I am not that familiar with JFlex, so I may not have the JFlex syntax exactly right):

```
id = ({letter}|_)({digit}|{letter})*
```

This would be equivalent to the regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]|_)([0-9]|[a-zA-Z])*
```

Comment: JFlex doesn't insist that you use macros. And it also provides predefined character classes `[:jletter:]` and `[:jletterdigit:]`, although those might not be what is being looked for since they include other Unicode letters.

Comment: @rici I know and wouldn't underscore be included in `[:jletter:]` also?

Comment: Thanks that helped. I am confused with two other rules: < character > Any character, with normal escapes \n, \t, \', \"
and Comments begin with "#" and extend to the end of a line. can you help with this as well?

Comment: I considered this related to the original question.

Comment: I said what i said because, as I said, I am not that familiar with the specifics of JLex and I don't want to give you misinformation.. But if you want to skip a comment that begins with `#` then the regex should be `#.*\n`. The `.` in the regex will match any character except newline 0 or more times and `\n` will match the newline character.  If you don't want to include the newline, then just `#.*`.  But as far as the escaped character, my best guess is `\\[a-zA-Z'\"]`. The  \\ matches a single '\' and `[a-zA-Z'\"]` matches a letter or single or double-quote (which must be escaped in JLex).

Comment: Yes, it's *related* to the original question in that it is a JLex question. But it's a new JLex question.

Comment: You can usually also backslash-escape backslashes. (Otherwise, there'd be no way to write one.) As for `[:jletter:]`, I don't think it includes underscore, but it should include things like `ñ`.

Comment: acn you share any resource to learn Regular expressions thoroughly? Thankyou

Comment: A basic online tutorial [here](https://regexone.com/). And Google **best resources to learn regular expressions**.